# Font-face in plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to use a custom icon font for a plugin, so I added it with font-face like so:

```css
/* styles.css */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'scrawlfont';
  src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot');
  src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

My folder structure is as follows:

```
plugin directory/
  resources/
    css/
      styles.css (contains the font-face snippet above)
      fonts/
        icomoon.eot
        icomoon.woff
        icomoon.ttf
        icomoon.svg
```

**Problem**

When I load my page I get 404 not found errors for all font files except .eot

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Font-face error]
[(Click to enlarge)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KipUf.png)

Any thoughts appreciated, Mario

**EDIT: Solution:**

I had wrong permissions on my font folder and files.
I set correct permissions using:

```
chmod 755 fonts/
chmod 644 fonts/*
```

Comment: Where are your fonticon-files located?

Comment: @VictorIn I just added my folder structure, they are in a subfolder near the css file

Answer (score 1):

Your paths and file-names look good to me. Since everything except .eot gives you a 404 error, I assume it has something to do with the [MIME Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type), or browser support:

On Apache and IIS you sometimes have to add the MIME-Types yourself, see:

- [Answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7374640/3589841)
- [Firefox @fontface cross domain errors & workarounds](https://coderwall.com/p/v4uwyq)

Also check if your fonts load on other browsers, if so check out this article:

- [Mo' Bulletproofer @Font-Face](http://readableweb.com/mo-bulletproofer-font-face-css-syntax/)

.

P.S. Also since every resource request goes through the `ìndex.php`, it might as well be a Craft bug.

Comment: I tried adding the Mimetypes but no luck. Then I tried on Windows and Wampserver and had no errors. Back to linux and after some digging I found the culprit: permissions! So, I changed the folder to 755 and the font files to 644 and tada it's working!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.